# Having an Issue Defining Variable Globally In jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to keep what I save in local storage on the page, that way if I were to refresh I would still have whatever I entered in the textarea box.

However I'm not sure if it's because I am using a variable that assigns to `e.target` then the relative path to what I am trying to save, but when I `console.log` my variable it says it's not defined and I'm assuming that my issue is because I don't fully understand jQuery.

```js
function updateHours() {}

function handleSave(e) {
  var value = $(e.target).siblings('.description').val()
  var hour = $(e.target).closest('.time-block').attr('id')
  localStorage.setItem(hour, value)
}

function main() {
  updateHours();
  $(document).on('click', '.saveBtn', handleSave)
  console.log(localStorage.getItem(value))
}

$(document).ready(main)
```

Comment: The issue is because `value` is only declared within the scope of the `handleSave()` function, and is only set after the `.saveBtn` element is clicked. I would assume that onload of the page, when you call `main()`, you'll need to loop through *all* the `.description` elements and retrieve their values from localStorage. This is just a guess though, without seeing the HTML.

Comment: Where does value come from? It's only declared in handleSave but not in Main()

Comment: `localStorage.getItem` also expects the identifier (In this case, you are passing in `hour` when you store the data), so assuming you made `value` global, `localStorage.getItem(value)` probably still wouldn't return the data you are looking for.

Comment: ^^^^ thanks for all the comments and yeah dbs you were exactly right it didn't at all. found my answer by doing this code below basically had to filter it through the class where the text was being held in and I found out that I just needed to define hour. thanks for the help :D                                                                                  
       $('.description').each(function(){ 
            var hourId = $(this).closest('.time-block').attr('id');
            description = localStorage.getItem(hourId);
            $(this).text(description)
        })

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function updateHours(){
    document.querySelectorAll('.time-block').forEach(el => {
        const savedValue = localStorage.getItem(el.id);
        const description = el.querySelector('.description');
        if (savedValue && description) {
            console.debug("Load value", el.id, savedValue);
            description.value = savedValue;
        }
    });
}

function handleSave(e){
    const el = e.target.closest('.time-block');
    if (!el) { return; }
    
    const description = el.querySelector('.description');
    if (!description) { return; }
    
    console.debug("Save value", el.id, description.value);
    localStorage.setItem(el.id, description.value);
}

function main(){
    updateHours();
    
    document.addEventListener('click', e => {
        if (!e.target.classList.contains('saveBtn')) { return; }
        handleSave(e);
    });
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', main);
```